# No scroll bar showing by default, if there more rows in Extjs (6.0.0.640) Grid and Combo box

Tags: extjs, extjs6

In the grid and combo box, if there is more data by default scroll bar not showing in a few of the systems.

How can we resolve it?
EXT JS version - 6.0.0.640

Both the system with the working scroll bar and the system with the problem have identical system configurations and OS.

Comment: This is a weird Behavior if the systems are in fact identical (even browser version). I would first look into layouts, heights and flex options. 
If you share some code or maybe even a fiddle it would be very useful.

Comment: We have tested with the below Kitchen sink grid, for this too it's not showing a scroll bar.

https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#array-grid

'OS: Windows 10 Enterprise - #Version -> 22H2 #OS Build - > 19045.3086'
'Chrome: Version 114.0.5735'

Comment: The seems to be framework issue that was fixed in newer versions. https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/examples/kitchensink/#row-expander-grid
The row expander example also does not display a scroll bar on 6.0.0

Comment: We have upgraded to ExtJS 6.7.0 version from 6.0.0, scroll bar issue got resolved.